# VaadIn Visual Designer - panel issue

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin, vaadin7

I created an VaadIn Design with the Visual Designerfrom Vaadin Labs

Its basic an login panel

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" name="design-properties" content="{&quot;RULERS_VISIBLE&quot;:true,&quot;GUIDELINES_VISIBLE&quot;:false,&quot;SNAP_TO_OBJECTS&quot;:true,&quot;SNAP_TO_GRID&quot;:true,&quot;SNAPPING_DISTANCE&quot;:10.0,&quot;PAPER_WIDTH&quot;:1440,&quot;PAPER_HEIGHT&quot;:900,&quot;JAVA_SOURCES_ROOT&quot;:&quot;src&quot;,&quot;THEME&quot;:&quot;sws_7_2&quot;}">
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <v-panel caption="Login" width="40%" height="40%" _id="login"> 
   <v-vertical-layout spacing="true" size-full="true" margin=""> 
    <v-horizontal-layout spacing="true" width-full="true"> 
     <v-label size-auto="true" plain-text="" :middle="" :right="" _id="lblLoginName">
       Login naam : 
     </v-label> 
     <v-text-field :middle="" _id="txtLoginName"></v-text-field> 
    </v-horizontal-layout> 
    <v-horizontal-layout spacing="true" width-full="true"> 
     <v-label size-auto="true" plain-text="" :middle="" :right="" _id="lblPassword">
       Paswoord : 
     </v-label> 
     <v-text-field :middle="" _id="txtPassword"></v-text-field> 
    </v-horizontal-layout> 
    <v-horizontal-layout spacing="true" width-full="true"> 
     <v-button plain-text="" :middle="" :right="" _id="btnLogin">
       Login 
     </v-button> 
     <v-button plain-text="" :middle="" _id="btnCancel">
       Annuleren 
     </v-button> 
    </v-horizontal-layout> 
    <v-horizontal-layout spacing="true" width-full="true"> 
     <v-button plain-text="" :middle="" :center="" _id="btnLoginPasswordForgotten">
       Login / paswoord vergeten? 
     </v-button> 
    </v-horizontal-layout> 
    <v-horizontal-layout width-full="true"> 
     <v-label width="6px" plain-text="" :middle="" :center="" _id="lblError"></v-label> 
    </v-horizontal-layout> 
   </v-vertical-layout> 
  </v-panel>  
 </body>
</html>
```

When I call the loginscreen (code below) I see it but I can't do anything with it.  The ClickListner isn't working, I can't even change a label value or something ...

```
public class Login extends LoginDesign implements Button.ClickListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private UI mainUI;
private ClickListener listner = this;

public Panel createLoginPanel(UI mainUI) {
    this.mainUI = mainUI;
    LoginDesign login = new LoginDesign();
    btnLogin.addClickListener(listner);
    lblError.setValue("Problem");
    System.out.println(lblError.getValue());
    return login;
}....
```

I see the changed value of the lblError in the console, but not on the screen ... ?

Normally you create your buttons and you add the caption and the listener.  Here I need to add the listener seperatly ... ?!

I'm doing something wrong ... any suggestions!.  Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I took an instance of the generated file but you need to use the extended class .. .

```
public class Login extends LoginDesign implements Button.ClickListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private UI mainUI;

private ClickListener listner = this;

public Panel createLoginPanel(UI mainUI) {
    this.mainUI = mainUI;
    Login login = new Login();
    btnLogin.addClickListener(listner);
    lblError.setValue("Problem");
    System.out.println(lblError.getValue());
    return login;
}....
```

Solved it